# Submitting LSF job array using different arguments for each element of the array

Tags: bash, shell, jobs, lsf, job-queue

I'm trying to avoid submitting separate jobs. I have so far have this at the start of my script:

```
#!/bin/bash
#BSUB -P account 
#BSUB -q queue
#BSUB -W 48:00
#BSUB -n 2
#BSUB -R rusage[mem=40000]
#BSUB -J jobname[1-22]
#BSUB -a 000-176:1
#BSUB -eo jobname.%I.%a.err
#BSUB -oo jobname.%I.%a.out
```

And then submit the job as follows:

```
bsub < myscript.sh
```

I have also tried the `-i` option as well but that doesn't work either.

One more issue is that the ranges of input arguments are different for the different elements of the array. So for jobname[1] input arguments will range from 000-176 but for jobname[22] input arguments will range from 000-067.

Is there a way to do this without manually submitting the job 22 times or more?

Comment: `#BSUB -a 000-176:1` -a is used to specify an esub. So LSF will look for, and run, an esub named `$LSF_SERVERDIR/esub.000-176:1`.  LSF won't complain if the esub doesn't exist. Since 000-176 is the range of input arguments, just want to double check if the `-a` was a typo.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `$LSB_JOBINDEX` environment variable inside your script, which is set to the index number of the particular array element at execution time.

Comment: Well, `$LSB_JOBINDEX` indicates the index 1 to 22.  Within every index, they have their own input variables of different ranges. So I don't think this will work unless I submit 22 different scripts (which I'm avoiding)

Comment: The point is that you can write your script to check which index you are then call your command with the appropriate argument.  That way you only have to submit one job array.